# Accessing an enum type inside a struct with generics

Tags: swift, generics

I have a struct with generics as such:

```
struct A<Content: View>: View {

    enum MyEnum {
    case abc
    case def
    }
    // ...
}
```

now, when I try to define a variable of this enum, like this:

```
class B: ObservableObject {

@Published var variable: A.MyEnum = .abc

}
```

I get an error:

`Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred`

what am I missing?

Comment: I nest this kind of stuff inside of `AnyA` because Swift doesn't provide a native mechanism for it with good naming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the enum is inside of a struct with a generic, The struct has to be typed before you can access its contents.

```swift
let x = A<Text>.MyEnum.abc
```

I would make the enum top level instead of a child of A.